# LGPL: Si uso QT no puedo vender mi programa y además tengo que revelar el código que utilicé?

Tags: qt

Quiero trabajar en un proyecto en C++ y para el GUI pienso elegir a QT, pero al ser LGPL tengo que dejar público los binarios de QT + mi código

Aquí tengo dos opciones: seguir buscando una librería para GUI C++ que pueda usar comercialmente... o al terminar el proyecto contactar con QT para migrar la licencia a la comercial.

Comment: Con la licencia LGPL solo tienes que hacerlo publico para tus clientes, no necesariamente para el publico en general.

Comment: Ademas por los términos de cualquiera de las licencias no puedes cambiar entre ellas, si creas un proyecto con la licencia LGPL no la puedes cambiar a Comercial o viceversa.

Answer (score 2):

En el caso de uso que describes, **sí** puedes distribuir software sin liberar la parte del código, dado que es "trabajo que ocupa la biblioteca (Qt)" y no "trabajo derivado" en la medida que enlaces dinámicamente tu binario a los binarios de Qt (`.so` en linux y OSX, `.dll` en Windows).

De [la entrada sobre LGPL en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License#Diferencias_con_la_GPL):

> Un programa que no contiene derivado de ninguna porción de la biblioteca, pero está diseñado para trabajar con la biblioteca al ser compilado o enlazado con ella se denomina un "trabajo que usa la biblioteca". Dicho trabajo, por separado, no es un trabajo derivado de la biblioteca, y por tanto cae fuera del ámbito de esta Licencia.

Esto es a grandes rasgos, pero debes revisar acuciosamente todas [las licencias involucradas](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/licenses-used-in-qt.html) a la hora de distribuir un binario. Según qué necesitas distribuir, tienes distintas obligaciones: desplegar licencias, proveer los binarios de Qt y su código fuente (pero no el tuyo), por ejemplo.

Hago la aclaración de que si bien he tenido experiencia previa en este ámbito, debes asesorarte con alguien con algún grado profesional en leyes, ojalá con alguna experiencia previa en este tema técnico.

Answer (score 0):

La versión 4 de Qt puede ser usada con fines comerciales sin necesidad de publicar el código fuente... Con la versión 5 la cosa cambia.

Creo recordar que hasta la versión 5.6 se utiliza una combinación de licencias [LGPL V2.1](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html) y [LGPL V3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.en.html). Pero a partir de la versión 5.7 solo está disponible la licencia [LGPL V3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.en.html) (aparte de la comercial).

Esto pluede plantear ciertos problemas ya que hay librerías, como QtChart, que no están adscritas a esta licencia sino a [GPL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) y aquí ya entramos en un terreno pantanoso donde quizás hiciera falta alguien con experiencia en temas de derecho digital para indicar cómo podrías hacer uso de, por ejemplo, QtChart, si usas Qt bajo la licencia [LGPL V3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.en.html). Quizá se pueda o quizá no.